# Service to generate spring boot executable jar

Tags: java, continuous-integration

I have a question regarding building and integrate my Java project. My source is located on BitBucket. Is there an online tool where I can build and install my Maven project? My goal is that the source on BitBucket is used and compiled. Afterwards it would be great to download the generated jar-file from the provider.

Thanks for your help,
Thomas

Answer (score 0):

## If your question is about online development

You can open your project in  a [Gitpod](https://www.gitpod.io/docs/bitbucket-integration). It provides a full fledged editor and terminal wherein you can install dependencies and build your application. Has a bitbucket integration to directly port your code to the editor.

## If your question is about continuous integration

You can add CI integration with [BitBucket Pipelines](https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/get-started-with-bitbucket-pipelines.) or [Circle CI](https://circleci.com/integrations/bitbucket/) to your application and write Jobs and Stages in a dedicated config file ( depending on your chosen CI tool ) to build, test and deploy your java application.

Comment: Hello! Thanks for your feedback. The question is regarding continues integration. But the goal is not only building and check the code quality by executing unit tests. The goal is to generate jar files and store it on a server where I can download it. Is there a provider which not only providing bulding the software and also providing the possiblity to store the jar file on it?

Comment: The typical flow is to build, test and then deploy the artifact ( jar file ) into a package registry. Bitbucket does not have a package registry ( see https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/Bitbucket-Package-Registry/qaq-p/1125234) but you can upload your artifact to  gilab registry ( https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/maven_repository),  Nexus ( https://www.sonatype.com/products/repository-pro ) or Github registry (  https://github.com/features/packages )

Comment: Thanks for your help

Comment: @Thomas, can you upvote the coment if it was useful? Thansks.